Subgraph in multigraph
The image below shows a not-so-trivial, but heavily scaled-down version in terms of number of nodes of the problem I'm facing.
Suppose that there's a start node, labelled "a" and a goal node, labelled "Z" in a multigraph. Between "a" and "Z" there are lots of paths, like "a-Z", "a-b-g-Z", etc. (highlighted with bold in the picture), which, combined form a graph of their own.
Is it there a standard algorithm to identify this sub-graph?


You would have to visit all of the vertices anyway, so why not use an exhaustive depth-first search?

Yes, there is such an algorithm.
A vertex v is part of the subgraph if and only if: v is reachable from a in G \ {Z}, and v is reachable from Z in G \ {a}.
All you need to do is implement a "reachability algorithm" (a simple graph traversal does the job) for every vertex in the graph.
Edit: this solution is not correct.  One has to verify that there exists a path p1 from a to v and there exists a path p2 from v to Z such that p1 and p2 are disjoint. A naive implementation could quickly become intractable for large graphs.

This doesn't seem correct. See vertex d in the graph above.

Indeed, the problem is a bit harder. One has to verify that there exists a path p1 from a to v and there exists a path p2 from v to Z such that p1 and p2 are disjoint.
